# Trigger an action when selecting on one of the option of dropdown-menu

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown-menu

[image]

I want to trigger something when selecting on one of the option.
I've tried

```
$.each(objects.assignments, function(index, value) {
    $('#group-' + index).click(function() {
        updateInfo(index);
        chart.draw(data[index], options);
        if ( index == 0 ){
          $("#as-dd.dropdown").text('Summary');
          console.log("A");
        }
        else{
          $("#as-dd.dropdown").text('Group ' + index);
           console.log("B");
        }
    });
});
```

---

- I got no error in the console.
- I also got nothing to display in the console.

How do I trigger anything when selecting on one of the option ?

Am I not suppose to use the `.click()` ?

Any helps / suggestions on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a .each() or a .click(). Use the .change() method like this

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  // based on the selectedValue you can do something
});
```

Comment: How do I loop through all my `objects.assignments` ?

Comment: You said `// based on the selectedValue you can do something` , so how do I know which one is selected ?

Comment: Can you please adjusting my code ? I feel like I don't have a clear image of what you're suggesting.

Comment: can you please give a sample of how `objects.assignments` looks like ? and how your `select` element looks like ?

Comment: objects.assignments , just loop 5 times because it containing 5 objects.

Comment: `<select class="dropdown" id="as-dd"> <option class="group" id="group-0"> Summary </option><option class="group" id="group-1">Group 1</option><option class="group" id="group-2">Group 2</option></select>`

Comment: the `option` element should have a `value` attribute not a `class` not `id`. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/js3o1dfx/

Comment: Thank you for your fiddle. I should use value to trigger - right ?

Comment: yes, based on the value you get there, you have to iterate your objects.assignments or directly access it (based on the objects.assignments structure). Here is a small example that demonstrates a simpler case http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/js3o1dfx/1/

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `click`, you need `change`:

```
$.each(objects.assignments, function(index, value) {
    $('#group-' + index).change(function() {
        updateInfo(index);
        chart.draw(data[index], options);
        if ( index == 0 ){
          $("#as-dd.dropdown").text('Summary');
          console.log("A");
        }
        else{
          $("#as-dd.dropdown").text('Group ' + index);
           console.log("B");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `.change` doesn't seem to work with my situation. I still see nothing is displaying on my console.log. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: After the `change` function, add this just to check if it's working: `alert("hello");` What happens now?

Comment: That means that this (`'#group-' + index`) isn't the correct id for the select box. You need to figure out what this is